# Can you make money with your shiny app by using some R packages?

Tags: shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard, shinyjs

I wonder if i can make a shiny app using some of these popular R packages such as : dtplyr, plyr, ggvis, gdata, ggplot2, etc and then selling this app online.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question and doesn't belong on StackOverflow

Comment: No offence mate, i think this question belong to the programming section and i am asking if i can monetize my app using some r packages

Comment: No offence taken. This is not a programming question as it does not involve coding specifics, if you're asking about licensing/legality then the question is too broad (narrow it down). As it stands, it is hard to clarify what type of question this is

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow, thats why i didnt realize that i am in the wrong section!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because not programming

Answer (score 1):

It is only a problem of license. You should check the license for each of those packages. For example GNU GPL does not prevent you from selling your app or making a profit, but then you must make the source code available. BSD license let you do everything you want, and you are not forced to release the source code.